# Calling a class having its name as a string

Tags: java, class

I have a string which specifies the name of the call.
How can i call the particular class by using this string.am trying this in java.
A function will return me a list of strings which are class names.now task is to make a call to a  class by using this string.

Comment: I don't mean this to sound unduly harsh, but your question contains all sorts of confusions. For example, first you say you have a single string, then you say you have a list of strings, then you again say the task is to use "this string", as if there is only one string. Also, "the name of the call" doesn't make sense and if I were to guess what it meant, I would not guess that it is the name of the class. If you are to become good at programming, and if you are to become good at asking questions on Stack Overflow, you must learn to think and write more clearly. Take some more time.

Comment: and what is meant by "make a call to a class"? Call a method of that class?

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using this code:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(yourString);
```

As the class name you should use the full class name including packages. But you can't call a class. You can initialize a class and then call a method of this class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String

Comment: +1: Suggest you link javadocs from Java 6 as Java 1.4.2 has been "End Of Life" for a number of years.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Class.forName(className)`. See [Java API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 2):

```
public class FooBar
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class test = Class.forName("FooBar");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/). By reflection you can get class by its name.

Comment: Link is not working anymore. → [Java Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)